# How to display an employee's worked time by date?

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net

I hope someone can help me. I have the below HTML table on my website that I want to populate as it's showed below. I'm using Ajax to get the data from a Webmethod in my code behind; I'm able to receive the data just fine but I'm having problems with my SQL query.

[image]
I have the following SQL query:

```
 SELECT TimeSheetId, Week, Departmentname, Employee, Activity,
CASE WHEN datename(dw,WorkDate)='MONDAY' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIME, 108) END AS Monday,
CASE WHEN datename(dw,WorkDate)='TUESDAY'THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIME, 108) END AS Tuesday,
CASE WHEN datename(dw,WorkDate)='WEDNESDAY'  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIME, 108) END AS Wednesday,
CASE WHEN datename(dw,WorkDate)='THURSDAY' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIME, 108) END AS Thursday,
CASE WHEN datename(dw,WorkDate)='FRIDAY' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIME, 108) END AS Friday,
CASE WHEN datename(dw,WorkDate)='SATURDAY' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIME, 108) END AS Saturday
--Time) as TotalHours
FROM TimeSheet
WHERE Week = 8 AND Departmentname = 'All' AND Employee = 'Hand Batis'
```

The Query returns the following:

[image]

How can I format the query result to make the time field appear under each day of the week according to the date? As well, I would like to display the sum of the time in the Total HRW column on the website.

The result should be something like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Why solve that with a query? Better to sum the values in the resulting dataset with Linq or something similar.

Comment: Hey @VDWWD, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to stick with SQL for simplicity purposes.

Comment: Then you should look into a nested select that sums the data.

Comment: Hey @VDWWD, I've updated my question with a new query that I put together, can you help get the result as the last image above?

Comment: I meant something like this: `SELECT TimeSheetId, Week, (SELECT SUM(Hours) WHERE Week = 'monday') AS Hours WHERE Week = 'monday'`